# Remove ID:s with only one observation in time in r

Tags: r

Hi I have panel data and would like to remove any individuals that only have observations at one time point and keep the ones that have 2 points in time.

so the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,6), time = c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2))

   id time
1  1    1
2  2    1
3  2    2
4  3    1
5  3    2
6  4    1
7  4    2
8  5    2
9  6    2
```

becomes this:

```
   id time
1  2    1
2  2    2
3  3    1
4  3    2
5  4    1
6  4    2
```

i.e removing individual 1, 5 and 6 so that the panel is balansed.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using a couple of options.  With `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'id', we get the number of rows (`.N`) and `if` that is greater than 1, get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N>1) .SD, by = id]
#   id time
#1:  2    1
#2:  2    2
#3:  3    1
#4:  3    2
#5:  4    1
#6:  4    2
```

---

Can use the same methodology with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(n()>1)
#    id  time
#   (dbl) (dbl)
#1     2     1
#2     2     2
#3     3     1
#4     3     2
#5     4     1
#6     4     2
```

---

Or with `base R`, get the `table` of data.frame, check whether it is greater than 1, subset the `names` based on the logical index ('i1') and use it to `subset` the 'data.frame' using `%in%`.

```
 i1 <- table(df$id)>1
 subset(df, id %in% names(i1)[i1] )
```

Comment: great base solution! :)

Comment: used the data.table solution, works perfectly! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another option,

```
ind <- rle(df$id)$values[rle(df$id)$lengths > 1]
df[df$id %in% ind,]
#  id time
#2  2    1
#3  2    2
#4  3    1
#5  3    2
#6  4    1
#7  4    2
```

Comment: You may have to specify that the 'id' is ordered

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = "id")[(duplicated(id) | duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE))]
#   id time
#1:  2    1
#2:  2    2
#3:  3    1
#4:  3    2
#5:  4    1
#6:  4    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` package to do this

```
 library(dplyr)
    df %>% group_by(id,time) %>% summarize(count = n()) %>%
           filter(!count == 1)
```